# Elasticsearch percolation on nested object with geobounding box filter

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch, nested

I have got an issue for few days and I have no idea how can I resolve it.

I am using elasticsearch 1.1.0.

I have a type containing the following mapping:

```
    {
    "location": {

       " type": "nested",
       " properties": {
            "accuracy": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "date": {
               " type": "date"
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
        ...
        "point": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }

}
```

I created a percolator using geo bounding box filter of elasticsearch :

```
 {
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "match_all":{

            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "nested":{
               "filter":{
                  "geo_bbox":{
                     "point":{
                        "top_left":[
                           4.559326171875,
                           45.08127861241874
                        ],
                        "bottom_right":[
                           5.2130126953125,
                           44.692088041727814
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               },
               "path":"location"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But when I am trying to percolate this document, which is obviously inside the bounding box , I have no matches:

```
{
  "doc": {
    "location": {
      "point": "44.933, 4.9",
      "date": "2014-05-21T08:40:05"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why I get this problem. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the solution of the problem with the help of some ElasticSeearch developper.

I quote:

"The toplevel type field forcefully defines what mapping is used during parsing of the percolator query. If not specified it tries to resolve the fields in the queries automatically in all mappings in geonestedindex index and there might be other locations fields in other types, that may end up being used."

In fact in my mapping I had two types havined the property

```
 "point": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
```

So if in my percolator I don't specify the type like this the percolation never matched:

```
  {
       "query":{
          "filtered":{
             "query":{
                "match_all":{

                }
             },
             "filter":{
                "nested":{
                   "filter":{
                      "geo_bbox":{
                         "point":{
                            "top_left":[
                               4.559326171875,
                               45.08127861241874
                            ],
                            "bottom_right":[
                               5.2130126953125,
                               44.692088041727814
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "path":"location"
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "type": "myType"
    }
```

With this percolator, the document could match easily.